# Simple jQuery nested unordered list navigation for mobile click function on parent <li>

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I am making a nested unordered navigation list for mobile device.

I simply want to collapse the ul ul if the li.dropdown is clicked again. So only one ul ul is visible at any one time. Works OK now but not on the parent li only if another li is clicked.

Need some help with my jQuery script.

Current state example:

http://codepen.io/Kerrys7777/pen/WroGPz

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("div.ehtm ul li:has(ul)").addClass("dropdown");
  $('div.ehtm > ul > li.dropdown > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("div.ehtm ul li.dropdown").click(function() {
      $("li.open").removeClass("open");
      $(this).addClass('open');
    });

  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="ehtm">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4-3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2-4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
}

ul
{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background:#FAFAFA; 
}

ul li
{
    border-top:1px solid #666;
}

ul li a
{
    padding:12px;
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.ehtm > ul > li.dropdown > a:after
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:8px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 4px dashed #666;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;     
}

ul ul
{
    display:none;   
}

ul li.open ul
{
    display:block;
    background:#e3e3e3;
}

ul li.open ul li
{
    padding-left:20px;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("div.ehtm ul li:has(ul)").addClass("dropdown");

    $("div.ehtm ul li.dropdown").click(function() {
      if(!$(this).hasClass('open')) {
      $('li.open').removeClass('open');
    } 
 $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

Only one drop down is opened as time
 When we click on the arrow that drop down gets collapsed

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("div.ehtm ul li:has(ul)").addClass("dropdown");
 $('div.ehtm > ul > li.dropdown > a').click(function(e) 
    e.preventDefault();
 });
 $("div.ehtm ul li.dropdown").click(function() {
      $("li.open").not($(this)).removeClass("open");
      if($(this).hasClass('open')){
      $(this).removeClass('open'); 
  }
      else{
         $(this).addClass('open');
      }
    });
});
```